# Using form input without updating model Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I would like to put a form on one of my pages, but don't want to use form_for to update a model.  I am basically using this like a filtering/searching system, where the user inputs something, and the page changes based on what the user input.  I know this is a pretty simple problem, but I'm also a little new to Rails.

Note:  I have the ability to filter the results if I can just get the input value.  I just need access to the input value in my Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `form_for` with a symbol as argument rather than an instance variable.

You can access the form data in your controller by referencing your params, just like you normally would. Let's say you have a form kinda like this:

```
<%= form_for :search do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :query %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

You'll then get the contents of the search form by calling `params[:search][:query]` in your controller.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

Comment: How do I access the values passed into this form?  If I'm using them on a page, say "Relationships", how do I access them in the Relationships controller?

Comment: By reference to your params, just like you would normally.

Answer (score 0):

you need [meta_search](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/meta_search)

```
<%= form_for @search, :url => articles_path, :html => {:method => :get} do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title_contains %>
  <%= f.text_field :title_contains %><br />
  <%= f.label :comments_created_at_greater_than, 'With comments after' %>
  <%= f.datetime_select :comments_created_at_greater_than, :include_blank => true %><br />
  <!-- etc... -->
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: so if I do this, would I use params[:search][:title_contains] to get the value in the first text field?